# How do I update just retrieved records without issuing an additional query?

Tags: sql, jdbc, derby

I have the following piece of code:

```java
String sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = " + email;
prestat = DBConnection.prepareStatement(sql);
rs = prestat.executeQuery();
boolean isEmpty = !rs.first();
if (isEmpty) {
  // Special marker for nonexistent user
  return "$null";
} else if (password.equals(rs.getString(2))) {
  String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
  // Here I want to insert the UUID into the database
}
```

Considering that I have already searched the database, I'm wondering if there is a way I can get the row number/position,and use it to update the UUID column, hence preventing another DB search.

Comment: I'm using Apache Derby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear what you are trying to do here, and it doesn't really seem you understand what goes on. For example, when using a prepared statement, one doesn't feed it with two concatenated strings, but instead does:

```
PreparedStatement stmt =
        conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar = ?");
stmt.setString(1, "Hello World!");
```

Then, if you really want to avoid the double search, you can simply assume an optimistic point of view:

```
UPDATE users SET uuid = ? WHERE email = ? AND password = ?
```

Ensure that the email is unique, by the way. Also, maybe you already do it, but don't save plaintext passwords in the db. Use cryptographic hashes instead, and salt them.

Since you specify that your backend is Apache Derby, maybe [this guide](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ad-trifecta12/) can help you solve your problem (it's 100% Java but not truly portable because of different backends may not implement all of the required features). Basically, you pass two flags when preparing the statement:

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement(
    ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, 
    ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");
```

and then you have a `ResultSet` backed by an updateable cursor, so you can call:

```
res.updateString("uuid", uuid);
res.updateRow();
```

I think this *may* avoid the additional search, however I didn't test it and cannot say if there's a real performance gain. Sounds like premature optimization, though.

Comment: I'm just beginning the development. will add the hashing soon.
And about the stmt.setString(), is there any performance difference?
And about the double search, I don't get how the update will prevent a second search. My question is, how do i avoid the second search, GIVEN that I have made the first search already. I need the first search for some other reason.

Comment: Don't search the first time with `SELECT`. Only `UPDATE`, since the conditions in the `WHERE` clause are the SQL equivalent of your two `if` blocks.

Comment: There may be performance advantages depending on the implementation, but the primary use for prepared statements is to strengthen your application against malformed (or malicious) input

Comment: if i do that, how do i differentiate between an email error and a password error? what if the user doesn't exist at all?

Comment: Without a bigger context I can't say if this is relevant, or if you can be ok by simply stating that email *or* password didn't match

Comment: See the updated answer for a solution which should work on Derby

Comment: By the way, you don't need to know if it was the password or the email that is wrong. Or at least, on a security point of view, it is a best practice not to mention it to the user so that eventual brute force attack can't get info on which user exists and which don't. I would also add you obviously store password in clear text which is also a bad idea, better use a hash (MD5 for example)

Answer (score 1):

well you could simply replace

```
prestat = DBConnection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email =" + email);
```

by

```
prestat = DBConnection.prepareStatement("Update users set uuid = '" + uuid + "' WHERE email =" + email);
```

And of course execute.

Comment: argh. sorry. my bad. i should've removed the statement. i know it's wrong. that is why i gave the comment.